# How to install matplotlib-cpp.h for visual studio 2019?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, header

Visual studio 2019 was used for c++ program project, where a plot library was required. [A document](https://matplotlib-cpp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which introduced [matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp) as a very useful c++ plotting library.

However, I wasn't sure how to install this library and include the library in a c++ project in visual studio. Especially, notice that the library used python environment as well.

How to install and use matplotlib-cpp.h in visual studio 2019?

Comment: On the GitHub page you linked, the `Vcpkg` section describes a method that will make it available to Visual Studio projects.

Comment: @NathanPierson I found a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRnjahwxZ8A ) to install vcpkg and matplotlib-cpp (Done). But when compiling an example vs encountered an error stating that "can nor open source file "python.h"". Going back to page (https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp/commit/edb40746123e2fdd194083f4e4a75cd985e5c593 ) it mentioned "Since a python interpreter is opened internally, it is necessary to link against `libpython` in order to user matplotlib-cpp" Do you know how to solve this part?

Comment: you can read this document for solving the problem:
https://matplotlib-cpp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/


and for adding C/C++ packages and libraries to Visual Studio this Document Can Help You: 
https://dev.to/dinhanhx/the-way-you-should-install-c-libraries-and-install-visual-studio-on-windows-10-3aj7